# How to call a variable from another scope?

Tags: java, scope

I am learning Java. I am coming from python, so scopes wasn't the biggest problem (at least for me it was straight forward). I am trying to make a simple receipt program. I need to call qualityOfService from the method ratingService() at the end of my receipt (I put a comment where I want it). How would I go about doing this? I have read other places about scopes, but it isn't really helping. Sorry for my formatting, I know how annoying it is to read horribly written code. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main 
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter your first name: ");
        String firstName = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the cost of your meal: ");
        double mealCost = userInput.nextDouble();
        String dummy = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the percentage of tip you want to leave: ");
        double tipPercentage = userInput.nextDouble();
        String dummy1 = userInput.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter the quality of service: ");
        int qualityOfService = userInput.nextInt();

        // calculate values
        double tipAmount = (double)mealCost * ((double)tipPercentage/100);
        double totalCost = (double)mealCost + (double)tipAmount;
        int numberOfTwentyDollarBills = (int)totalCost / 20;   

        // 
        System.out.println("Thank you " + firstName + " for choosing our resturant!");
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        System.out.println("Cost of Meal = " + mealCost);
        System.out.println("Percentage of tip = " + tipPercentage);
        System.out.println("Tip amount = " + tipAmount);
        System.out.println("Total cost of meal = " + totalCost);
        System.out.println("Total number of twenty dollar bills = " + numberOfTwentyDollarBills);
        System.out.println("Rating of your service = " + qualityOfService);
        System.out.println("=========================================");
        // calling ratingService() goes here.
    }

    // service rating method 
    public static void ratingservice() 
    {
        int qualityOfService = 1;
        if (qualityOfService == 1) {
            System.out.println("We are sorry you weren't happy with your serivce. Please let staff know if you have any concerns");
        }
        else if (qualityOfService == 2) {
            System.out.println("We are sorry you weren't happy with your serivce. Please let staff know if you have any concerns");
        }
        else if (qualityOfService == 3) {
            System.out.println("We are happy that you enjoyed your stay somewhat, please let staff know if you have any concerns.");
        }
        else if (qualityOfService == 4) {
            System.out.println("We are glad you enjoyed your stay! Please let our staff know if you have any concerns");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("We are glad you enjoyed your stay! Please let our staff know if you have any concerns");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Passing a variable isn't that different between Python and Java.

Comment: Not sure exactly of your problem. Why doesn't `ratingservice` return `qualityOfService` as an int and is void instead? Also, check [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please (the minimal part). Removing part of your code that doesn't have to do with the problem at hand makes it easier for us to read fast and understand what your problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `qualityOfService` a parameter on the `ratingservice` method.

```
public static void ratingservice(int qualityOfService) {...}
```

And then call it in the first method like so:

```
ratingService(qualityOfService)
```

---

This is because in Java we must pass all variables needed for a method into the method as parameters. Each method has its own scope of variables, and in order to pass a variable from one scope (the first method) into another scope (the second method), you must pass it as a parameter.

Another solution would be to create an instance variable in your class, but since these are static methods, that will not work. An instance variable can be used by all of the instance (non-static) methods of a class.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! Could you perhaps explain the syntax of that? I don't fully understand why it has to be done that way.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. Makes all sense now. Again, thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you *declare* `qualityOfService` inside the `main()` method, therefore it's ONLY available inside that method, if you want it to be available somewhere else, it has to be passed (this is what "scope" means).  Another option to the suggested solution would be to set it at the class level like so:

```
class Main {

    static int qualityOfService;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    ...stuff...
    qualityOfService = userInput.nextInt();
    ...
    }

    public static void ratingservice() 
    {
        if (qualityOfService == 1) {
            System.out.println("We are sorry you weren't happy with your serivce. Please let staff know if you have any concerns");
        }
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

In this case, because you *declared* it at the class level, even though you don't *initialize* it until you're in the `main()` method, it's available in any (static) method of the class.